# Installation script for OpenERP, creating directories under /var

Tags: shell-script, software-installation

I would like to know what this code means. I found it [on the OpenERP forum](http://forum.openerp.com/forum/topic36094.html). It is supposed to run on Linux CentOS.

```
adduser openerp
DIR="/var/run/openerp /var/log/openerp"
for NAME in $DIR
do
if [ ! -d $NAME ]; then
   mkdir $NAME
   chown openerp.openerp $NAME
fi
done
rm -rf openerp*
```

I got to know that we are creating user called openerp and after that i am not getting what they are telling.

Comment: please make the title more meaningful according to the subject.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let me ident your code to make it look in a more structured way(and to be easy to read).

```
adduser openerp 
DIR="/var/run/openerp /var/log/openerp" 
for NAME in $DIR do 
    if [ ! -d $NAME ]; then 
        mkdir $NAME 
        chown openerp.openerp $NAME 
    fi 
done 
rm -rf openerp*
```

After creating the user, the `for` loop will expand each item of the variable `DIR`, and check `if` this directory already exists([introduction to if](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)). If doesn´t, it will create it with `mkdir` and take the [ownership](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) with `chown` to the tuple of user and group called openerp.

The `rm -fr openerp*` will cleanup the source code directory so the rest of the script can donwnload and extract the openerp software:

```
wget http://nightly.openerp.com/7.0/nightly/src/openerp-7.0-latest.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openerp-7.0-latest.tar.gz  --transform 's!^[^/]\+\($\|/\)!openerp\1!'
```

If you take a look at the url being fetched by `wget` you will notice the **nightly** word. Taking it simple, means that this software was packaged or compiled "last night", and it have a more recent code than a stable release.